# How to replace all spaces except spaces inside "a b" in RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I replace all space characters with letter "_" except spaces inbetween characters "a" and "b" like this "a b".

```
// this is what I have so far to save someone time (that's a joke)
var result:String = string.replace(/ /g, "_");
```

Oh this is in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
var result:String = string.replace(/([^a]) | ([^b])/g, "$1_$2");
```

A simplified explanation of the above is that it replaces a space that either:

1. is preceded by a character other than `a`
2. is followed by a character other than `b`

Note: to generalize the regex to include tabs and newlines, use `\s`, like this:

```
var result:String = string.replace(/([^a])\s|\s([^b])/g, "$1_$2");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
/(?!a)\s(?!b)/g
```

**Edit:** This is not the best solution as KendallFrey pointed out.

Comment: This is wrong. This only replaces spaces that are not followed by `b`. The `(?!a)` does nothing.